# How to associate nested polygons to their parent from different GeoJSON files?

Tags: leaflet, gis, postgis

I have 3 separated GeoJSON files, each one contains a Feature Collection of Polygons.

First one for regions, the second for provinces and last for  communes.

So the scenario is: for each region on click or zoom, show provinces in the clicked region then same thing with procinces.

I am using Leaflet for interactive map.

I am stuck on how to link every region with their provinces.

Is there any way to detect nested polygons?

Do I need a database or server side analysis?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO!

You would like to be able to tell the child ("*nested*") polygons of a given parent / container polygon, so that when a user clicks on the latter, you can show only the former.

The easiest would be to embed in your GeoJSON data properties some ID to each Feature, and for each child the ID of its container parent, and/or for each parent the array (list) of its children.

If your GeoJSON data does not already contain such association, then you could refactor it once to make it available. You have plenty ways of doing so, whether in GIS software, or directly using Client libraries. E.g. have a look at http://turfjs.org/ and its [`booleanContains`](http://turfjs.org/docs#booleanContains) method:

> Boolean-contains returns True if the second geometry is completely contained by the first geometry. The interiors of both geometries must intersect and, the interior and boundary of the secondary (geometry b) must not intersect the exterior of the primary (geometry a).